# Add a custom column to order items and make it sortable in WooCommerce admin order details page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, hook-woocommerce

I have been working to add a item product attribute to the admin order details page - which I have managed. You can see the extra column titled "Packing Weight".

[image]

```
// Add custom column headers here
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers');
function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers() {
    // set the column name
    $column_name = 'Packing Weight';

    // display the column name
    echo '<th>' . $column_name . '</th>';
}

// Add custom column values here
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3);
function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values($_product, $item, $item_id = null) {
    // get the post meta value from the associated product
    // $value = get_post_meta($_product->post->ID, '_custom_field_name', 1);
    $value = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $_product->post->ID, 'pa_packing-order', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );

    // display the value
    echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
}
```

However, I would ideally like to order the items in the order by this column e.g. Very Soft, Soft, Hard. I am happy to change the values of packing weight to a numeric scale 1 - 10 if this makes ordering easier.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Note that I've added some CSS classes, to make it sortable
- Also notice that I'm using an array of strings for the output, and displaying them randomly. **Replace this with your own code.** This is because my products do not contain the specific terms

So to make your custom column added to admin order item sortable, you can use:

```php
// Add header
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers( $order ) {
    // Set the column name
    $column_name = __( 'Packing Weight', 'woocommerce' );
    
    // Display the column name
    echo '<th class="line_packing_weight sortable" data-sort="string-ins">' . $column_name . '</th>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 10, 1 );

//Add content
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values( $product = null, $item, $item_id ) {
    //  WC_Order_Refund OR WC_Order_item
    if ( $item->get_type() == 'shop_order_refund' ) {
        $item = new WC_Order_Refund( $item_id );
    } else {
        $item = new WC_Order_Item_Product( $item_id );

        // Only for "line_item" items type, to avoid errors
        if ( ! $item->is_type( 'line_item' ) ) return;
    }
    
    // Replace this part with your own code
    $some_strings = array( 'Soft', 'Very soft', 'Hard' );
    
    // Replace this part with your own code
    $value = $some_strings[array_rand( $some_strings )];
    
    if ( $value ) { 
        echo '<td class="line_packing_weight" data-sort-value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</td>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3 );
```